# Using jQuery and <audio>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

How can one interact with an `<audio>` element using jQuery, specifically to hide only the "seeking" part of an `<audio>` element?

I don't think the seeking part can be hidden by using plain HTML.

Comment: One could use [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/), which does all the hard work for you. It even includes a flash-based fallback for when `<audio>` or the particular codec used isn't supported by the browser.

Comment: I looked at jPlayer, but would rather use a custom own solution if possible.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from implementing your own UI with jPlayer as a backend... Your users wouldn't know and you get the advantages of jPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<audio>` tag does not have the "controls" attribute (or, I think if the attribute value is `false`), then no controls are shown. The HTML5 Boilerplate CSS hides audio elements without controls:

```
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
```

You shouldn't need JavaScript/jQuery at all.

Comment: I would only like to hide the "seeking" portion of the <audio> element. I just added the word "only" to the question to make it more clear.